# Merge 2 arrays of objects using ES6 and display objects in one array that doesn't appear in the other

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays of objects. One is the "master" containing objects with a `name` and a `data` field. The other array ("updates") is used to mutate the first one and contains objects of the same form.

I want to (a) merge "updates" into "master" but only if there is a matching `name` field (b) display a list of objects in the "updates" array that doesn't appear in the master.

I've been able to do it with plain old JavaScript but I would like to do it more elegantly with ES6.

```
let arr1 = [
    { name: "aaaa", data: 56 },
    { name: "bbbb", data: 34 },
    { name: "cccc", data: 25 },
    { name: "dddd", data: 78 },
    { name: "eeee", data: 12 },
    { name: "ffff", data: 12 }
];

let arr1 = [
    { name: "cccc", data: 101 },
    { name: "err1", data: 0 },
    { name: "dddd", data: 204 },
    { name: "err2", data: 0 }
]; 

// some clever ES6 code that generates result[] and errors[] arrays

result = [
    { name: "aaaa", data: 56 },
    { name: "bbbb", data: 34 },
    { name: "cccc", data: 101 },
    { name: "dddd", data: 204 },
    { name: "eeee", data: 12 },
    { name: "ffff", data: 12 }
]

errors = [
    { name: "err1", data: 0 },
    { name: "err2", data: 0 }
]
```

I expect there is a very elegant 2 or 3 line solution but so far, I have been unable to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to loop over the updates Array, use [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to take the `name` and `data` values

Use [`.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to check if the `name` exists in Update - If it does, update that entry. If it doesn't, push the update to Errors Array instead

```js
const master = [
    { name: "aaaa", data: 56 },
    { name: "bbbb", data: 34 },
    { name: "cccc", data: 25 },
    { name: "dddd", data: 78 },
    { name: "eeee", data: 12 },
    { name: "ffff", data: 12 }
];

const updates = [
    { name: "cccc", data: 101 },
    { name: "err1", data: 0 },
    { name: "dddd", data: 204 },
    { name: "err2", data: 0 }
];

const errors = [];

updates.forEach(({name, data}) => {
  let index = master.findIndex(x => x.name === name);
  
  index !== -1 ? master[index] = {name, data} : errors.push({name, data});
});

console.log(master);
console.log(errors);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you @Light - that is quite beautiful, elegant and refreshingly non-esoteric. I was able to pick it apart and understand it completely.

I don't see a "Make This the Answer" button but your solution certainly fits that bill

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping it would read okay! But weird about the answer thing, it should be a mark underneath the upvote / downvote button by the side [This link shows it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: I see it now.  Marked as answer and thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Adopting a set-based approach to this, you can provide functions to convert to/from your `name`/`data` pairs into a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

```
const toMapEntries = arr => arr.map(({ name, data }) => [name, data]);
const toMap = arr => new Map(toMapEntries(arr));
const fromMap = map => [...map].map(([k, v]) => ({ name: k, data: v }));
```

Now you can create some reusable functions that work over maps, first to merge all existing keys:

```
const merge = (map1, map2) =>
  new Map([...map1, ...[...map2].filter(([k]) => map1.has(k))]);
```

...then to split-out non-existing keys:

```
const diff = (map1, map2) => new Map([...map1].filter(([k]) => !map2.has(k)));
```

using them as follows:

```
const map1 = toMap(arr1);
const map2 = toMap(arr2);

const mergedResults = fromMap(merge(map1, map2));
const errorResults = fromMap(diff(map2, map1));
```

The advantage of using the map-based approach is that key-lookup on a map is an `O(1)` operation, meaning that the `merge` and `diff` functions have linear time-complexity. This might be important with large datasets.

Comment: Thank you @spender.  A lot to digest there but I'm experimenting with it now and learning a lot. Appreciate you laying it out like that in a reusable fashion and I like that it's O(1) - only small arrays right now but they might grow later.